# Which builder to use when using nx with angular.json

Tags: angular, angular-cli, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I migrated an existing angular project to use nx. But I am not quite sure if I did it the correct way, as the performance is very poor.

I now switched from

```
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
```

to

```
"builder": "@nrwl/web:build",
```

and it seems that the performance got better. But there are more, for example:

```
"builder": "@nrwl/angular:webpack-browser",
"builder": "@nrwl/angular:ng-packagr-lite",
```

Is it correct to use web:build? What are the differences? Unfortunately I cannot find a good explanation on their website. Anybody can point me to the right direction? Which builder to use when? What are the differences?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a couple of months, but for the sake of completeness: the ngPackagr one should be used for libraries only, as [specified in their repo](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr). Is that what you were trying to do? Also, what did you mean by poor performance?

If it's any reference (or for future visitors) I just created an NX app and it came with `@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser` by default.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30073153)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after an Nx update, so did a little search on their official website. It's sad that they don't provide sufficient documentation for migrations. However, as they have documented clearly in their [@nrwl/angular:webpack-browser](https://nx.dev/packages/angular/executors/webpack-browser) page,

> The webpack-browser executor is very similar to the standard browser builder provided by the Angular Devkit. It allows you to build your Angular application to a build artifact that can be hosted online. There are some key differences:
>
> - Supports Custom Webpack Configurations
> - Supports Incremental Building

A `customWebpackConfig` can be provided but is optional and still the `Angular Devkit Configuration` takes priority.

Nx configuration has now been updated to `version: 2` and `"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",` was the standard way of specifying the executor in `version: 1`. Check your Nx configuration version and if you want to update it to `2`, follow the instructions [here](https://nx.dev/configuration/projectjson#workspace-json).